# Ubuntu 9.10 server 32 bits

Tags: ubuntu-9.10

I'm a newbia at Unix but I installed for learning the 9.10 32 bits version and intead of the prompt i would like to have a windows interface. I tried to install the xorg program but can't find it. Is there another way?

THanks

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu Server only installs the basic console, but you can add the full X-windows desktop with this command:

```
sudo aptitude install ubuntu-desktop
```

That will install the [*ubuntu-desktop*](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/ubuntu-desktop) meta package and pull in all required packages.

However, it may be easier for you to download the non-server Ubuntu LiveCD and reinstall from there.